# CentOS has not DefaultDepth

Tags: centos, xorg

In `CentOS` there is no `DefaultDepth` line in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file to set the default color depth (although you can add this line to it). How does X determines which color depth to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the driver loaded, and defaults to 8-bit. From the [`xorg.conf(5)`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/xorg.conf.5.html) man page (emphasis mine):

> **DefaultDepth** *depth*
>
> specifies which color depth the server should use by default. The -depth command line option can be used to override this. **If neither is specified, the default depth is driver-specific, but in most cases is 8**.